# Wordpress loop iterates over the last 15 posts only

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a wordpress framework (WooFramework) that uses the following code to create a list of all posts of a specific category:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

I check the Wordpress documentation and this code seems right. However the list outputted contains only the 15 most recent posts. It seems like something is making the have_posts() stop earlier than it should. Any ideas on what may be causing this problem?

Tip: The index page shows (by default) the 15 most recent posts. Can that be related with the problem? Could it be possible that the framework redefined wordpress' have_posts() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to Settings > Reading and changing the value of "Blog Pages Show At Most". If you want to show *all* your posts you can just set it to something really high like 9999999999.

Comment: Dude, you just saved me!!! It worked perfectly! I would never have thought of that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh but there's a catch: now the homepage shows *all* posts ever posted (without pagination)... seems like a tradeoff